# Is there a standard XML schema for Java objects/classes?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

Is there an available, standard XML schema which describes the general structure and content of Java Objects? I have searched for this to no avail.

I am relatively new to both XML in general, and various Java based XML technologies (primarily JaxB) in particular, so forgive me if I have overlooked something.

Comment: What for? If it's for seralization, look up java xml serialzation.

Comment: I am writing a system which generates XML files whose elements include Java objects, hence I just wanted to know if there was a standard schema for such elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an official Oracle/Sun standard, but a third-party tool, JSX, serializes java objects to xml, and has an [XML Schema specification of its format](http://jsx.org/jsx.xsd).

The [example XML](http://jsx.org/) shows how it records the internal details of objects, including field types and inherited classes.

Even if you don't use this schema yourself, it would give you a starting point for the issues to be addressed by a format in order to fully represent object state.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What puts me down a bit is that it is proprietary...do you know of any open source alternatives?

Comment: @chrsva sorry, I couldn't find this last night, but there's also "Koala Object Markup Language". http://old.koalateam.com/XML/serialization/instances.html Unfortunately, because the project was last updated in [1999](http://old.koalateam.com/XML/serialization/), it predates XML schema, and so doesn't have one.  Another possibility I've heard of (but know nothing about) is a field called object modelling - UML, MOF, XMI, MDA - http://www.omg.org/mda/ (see bottom of page). They address Java and XML, so I'd expect there's a schema. SO has some of those tags, so maybe target them.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that there is no such standard schema.

When you serialize using something like JAXB, you effectively have a different XML schema for each class / network of classes that you bind.

---

A couple more observations:

- It would be possible to write an XML schema that is capable of representing any kind of Java object.  You would need an element for "object" which had an attribute called class name, child elements called "field" and so on.  But the resulting XML representations would take significantly more space, and would be difficult to read and to use.
- In JAXB and the like, there (clearly) is a systematic relationship between the network of classes and the XML structure, but it is not expressible as an XML schema.  Rather, it is a mapping that "generates" a schema from the classes, in a conceptual sense.  (In fact, it is analogous to what is happening in XMI, where a meta-model is mapped to an XML schema.)
- Referential integrity is beyond what is expressible in a XML schemas, but that is not the reason why there is no common schema.  Even if you ignore referential integrity and reduce the problem to "tree shaped", you still cannot generate a useful common schema for the kind of XML that JAXB, XMI and similar mappings produce.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Stephen!

That sounds strange though, isn't an XML schema comparable to the grammar definition for a programming language? It was my impressions that it was, and that as such it seemed reasonable that there would be schemas for describing well-defined structures such as Java classes.

Comment: Only loosely comparable.  Take a look at the XML for to different bound classes, and see if you can figure out if there is scope for a common XML schema.

Comment: @chrsva, the reason there isn't a 'standard' schema is that XML is a tree, whereas Java objects form a graph; they're not 1-to-1.  You need a custom schema to help with referential integrity.  Another tool to research is also Xstream (http://xstream.codehaus.org/)  Although, I tend to like JAXB more.

Answer (score 0):

An XMLSchema file describes what is possible and not possible in an XML document conforming to definitions of elements stored inside this XMLSchema file.

XMLSchema, in itself, is not related to Java : an XMLSchema file is here solely to check validity of XML files conforming to the XMLSchema file.

The Java people use XMLSchema file to generate Java source code that is able to receive data from XML file conforming the XMLSchema (the xjc tool).

You could also generate XMLSchema file from a set of Java source files (use schemagen tool for that).

When you have the following elements, you are able to use JAXB to marshall/unmarshall Java objects to/from XML files :

- XMLSchema files
- Java source files
- XML files

There are [other ways to marshall/unmarshall](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) xml data from/to Java.

Answer (score 0):

It is hypothetically possible to construct a sort of meta-schema that would allow all the possible XML files generated by JAX-B or some other serialization library. However, most people would not find such a schema useful, because it would permit such a broad range of XML documents as to be essentially unhelpful. Instead, people either start from a schema and generate Java classes, or start from a particular graph of java classes and generate a schema that reflects (haha) the particular data in it.